# Django EmalField form input is always set to active

Tags: django, forms, authentication, registration, input-field

so I have this form as on this image below. The point is that if the user clicks any of the fields, the text (which is essentialy a label, not a placeholder) rises up which shows that the clicked input field is active.

[image]

However, I've tried to create a customized user creation in Django, which is just to have the email as the main user identificator, not the username. Now everything else works as supposed, but the thing is that the email field always appears as active (you know, the css attribute).

I will now paste a scary amount of code and I will be happy if you could find out what's wrong. Sorry for the trouble

```
`class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    # handles user creation, havent' tested yet
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        # creates user with email as their id
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an username')
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('Users must have a password')
        
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            username=username,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(user=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
        # user model, was just trying out some stuff
        username = models.CharField(verbose_name='username', max_length=30)
        email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email', unique=True,
                                  max_length=60)
        date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined',
                                           auto_now_add=True)
        last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', 
                                          auto_now=True)
        is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
        objects = UserManager()
    
        USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
        REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'email', 'password']
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.email
        
        def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
            return self.is_admin
        
        def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
            return True`
```

Now the form part

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
# form to create a new user
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'email)'
```

And the view part

```
class RegisterView(FormView):
# registration form
form_class = RegisterForm
template_name = 'register.html'

def post(self, request):
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        print('yes')
        return redirect('login')
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

Again, I am so so sorry for the vaste amount of code, it's just that I'm lost and since I'm just learning this stuff it's hard for me to spot the error.

Thank you so much for any feedback

Comment: The problem is that your the email label appears upper your textfield ?

Comment: yes, the form should be only blue when the user clicks the input field (when it's focused), but for some reason it's blue even tho there is no text

Comment: Then you should add your html && css files. That does not have much to do with Django.